# Read through the table and display the dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a table that contains columns with rowspan and rows that do not contain rowspan.  I want to read the date column from the table below.

I want to read Monday 1 jan 2010, Tuesday 2 jan 2010. Wednesday 3 jan 2010...etc...
How can I do that?

Note that there are some columns with rowspan and others not.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
var maxcols = 0;

$('table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).children().length > maxcols ? maxcols = $(this).children().length : maxcols = maxcols;
});

$('table tr td:first-child').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != '' && $(this).parent().children().length === maxcols)
        alert($(this).text());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/FyGR6/1/

Comment: @learning - Just out of interest why did you unaccept this answer - did you find a problem with the code?

Answer (score 3):

```
var dates = [];

$('table tr td:first-child').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != '')
        dates.push( $(this).text() );
});
```

Comment: It seeems that where there are rowspan, it is reading the values in the column next to the first column

Comment: Could you post the html for your table?